# Return type mystery

Tags: powershell, return-type

I have something like the following in PowerShell

```
function x { 
    $result = New-Object 'System.Object[,,]' 1,1,1 
    'Type in function is: ' + $result.getType()
    $result[0,0,0] = 'dummy-value'
    return $result    
}

$result = x
$result.GetType()
```

It is peculiar that type of result is Object[,,] in the method but suddenly becomes Object[] outside. I basically need a few arguments of type Object[,,] for some .Net library that I am using.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happened, just try to type :

```
PS C:\temp> $result[0]
Type in function is: System.Object[,,]
PS C:\temp> $result[1]
dummy-value
```

The explanation is everything that is output frm the function is put into an array.

To do what you want you have to write this (don't forgot the , before $result) :

```
function x { 
    $result = New-Object 'System.Object[,,]' 1,1,1 
    $result[0,0,0] = 'dummy-value'
    return ,$result    
}
```

then :

```
PS C:\temp> $a = x
PS C:\temp> $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[,,]                               System.Array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was after! What does that magic comma do? (a,b,c) gives me an array bit this does not seem to apply here...

Comment: PowerShell expands an array when it's returned by a function. The ',' just gives an extrat array to expand, so we receive an array.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by extrat array? Extract array? An empty array. Could you elaborate the syntax ",var" in general?

Comment: In PowerShell , is the array operator : `$a=1,2` create a var `$a` with two integers. `$a=1` create a var containing one integer, so you can create an **array** with one integer writing `$a=,1`